# How to use a service defined in another package?

Tags: ros, include, package, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am facing a compilation problem when I try to include a service.h file in a node located in another package.
Here is the architecture :

```
rosfond/
    src/
        my_nodes.cpp
    include/
        ...
    srv/
        my_service.srv
hmi/
    src/
        my_other_nodes.cpp
    include/
        ...
```

I want to use `my_service` in the `hmi` package, and especially include `my_service.h` in `my_other_nodes.cpp`. For that,
I wrote at the beginning of `my_other_nodes.cpp`  `#include "rosfond/my_service.h"`.
I also use `my_service` in `my_nodes`.

When I try to compile my whole workspace, it fails. However, if I compile only `rosfond`, it works. So the problem seems to be related to how I include/link `my_service` in `my_other_nodes` and in the hmi's `CMakeLists.txt`.

Here are the `CMakeLists.txt` and the `package.xml` file of each package :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rosfond)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
add_service_files(DIRECTORY srv FILES my_service.srv)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES rosfond
 CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  include
)
add_executable(my_nodes src/my_nodes.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_nodes
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>rosfond</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The rosfond package</description>

  <maintainer email="ghost@todo.todo">ghost</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
</package>
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(hmi)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES hmi
 CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  include
)
add_executable(my_other_nodes src/my_other_nodes.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_other_nodes
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>hmi</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The hmi package</description>

  <maintainer email="ghost@todo.todo">ghost</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosfond</build_depend>
  <run_depend>rosfond</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
</package>
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The error message is : `my_other_nodes.cpp : rosfond/my_service.h: No such file or directory`.

Thanking you in advance for your answers,

roach

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242427/how-to-use-a-service-defined-in-another-package-?/) by [roach](https://answers.ros.org/users/27720/roach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

After some research, I have found one solution to my problem.
I have added `add_dependencies(my_nodes ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})` to the rosfond's `CMakeLists.txt` (only for the nodes that use `my_service`) as well as in the hmi's one (`my_nodes`changed into `my_other_nodes` obviously). I have also find_package-d rosfond in hmi's `CMakeLists.txt`.
In the rosfond's `package.xml`, <s>I have added the lines</s>

```
<export>
    <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/srv/cpp"/>
</export>
```

And the the hmi's one :

```
<run_depend>rosfond</run_depend>
<build_depend>rosfond</build_depend>
```

Thanks to these changes, I could include `rosfond/my_service.h` in `my_other_nodes.cpp`.

I hope this solution will work for you if you have the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [roach](https://answers.ros.org/users/27720/roach/) with karma: 116 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-31**:
That is basically how it should be done, but the `cpp flags` export is not needed / undesirable. That is a rosbuild thing (old build system). Catkin doesn't use those anymore (it's basically CMake). See http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-01-07**:
I second to @gvdhoorn. I crossed out the unnecessary portion in the body to avoid potential confusion for future readers.